# Importing HTML (orgmode-like) document with inline images to orgmode

Tags: org-mode

I often find myself wanting to save local copies of sites such as:

http://ase.tufts.edu/gsc/gradresources/guidetomixedmodelsinr/mixed%20model%20guide.html

I need to store a local copy of it (to read in my favourite editor). One solution of course is to use eww, but I would like to be able to port it through to Orgmode syntax so I can annotate it. I tried Pandoc, but couldn't seem to get the right filters. I end up with either no whitespace; or hundreds of html src blocks.

Any solutions would be appreciate. Inline images are a must (or at least saved).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use eww and copy the region of interest into an Orgmode
file.  (Option: If you have org-eww you could use its specialized
copy.)

Then mark the copy and call the following function
`org-inline-images-to-images-in-region`.  It stores copies of the
inline-images as attachments and places links to them in the Org file.

## +begin_src emacs-lisp

```
(require 'org)
(require 'org-attach)

(defun next-property-display-data (start limit)
  (let ((pos (next-property-change start nil limit)))
    (while
        (and (< pos limit)
             (let ((display-prop (plist-get (text-properties-at pos) 'display)))
               (or (not display-prop)
                   (not (plist-get (cdr display-prop) :data)))))
      (setq pos (next-property-change pos nil limit)))
    pos))

(defun org-attach-inline-image-with-hashed-name (text-properties)
  (let ((display-data (cdr (plist-get text-properties 'display))))
    (when display-data
      (let* ((data (plist-get display-data :data)))
        (when data
          (let* ((basename (sha1 data))
                 (org-attach-filename (concat (org-attach-dir t) "/" basename)))
            (unless (file-exists-p org-attach-filename)
              (with-temp-file org-attach-filename
                (setq buffer-file-coding-system 'binary)
                (set-buffer-multibyte nil)
                (insert data)))
            (org-attach-sync)
            org-attach-filename))))))

(defun org-inline-images-to-images-in-region (beg end)
  "Save the data of inline-images as attachment and insert a link to the attachment."
  (interactive "r")
  ;; I guess this should be refined.  todo: check out the
  ;; text-properties world!
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char beg)
    (when (and (plist-get (text-properties-at (point)) 'display)
           (plist-get (cdr (plist-get (text-properties-at (point)) 'display)) 'data))
      (let ((name (org-attach-inline-image-with-hashed-name
                   (text-properties-at (point)))))
        (goto-char (next-property-change (point) nil end))
        (insert "[[" name "]]" )))
    (let ((pos (next-property-display-data (point) end)))
      (while (< pos end)
        (goto-char pos)
        (let ((name (org-attach-inline-image-with-hashed-name
                     (text-properties-at (point)))))
          (goto-char (next-property-change (point) nil end))
          (insert "[[" name "]]" ))
        (setq pos (next-property-display-data (point) end))))))
```

## +end_src

Note that the stored images get their sha1-hashes as filenames.

To have Emacs recognize the images with the sha1-hash-names insert
regexp "[1234567890abcdef]{40}" into config variable
image-file-name-regexps.  (E.g. via M-x customize-apropos
image-file-name-regexps)

Comment: Meanwhile there is org-attach-embedded-images.el in the contrib directory of Org which is more or less the answer above.